# How to have a model field be based on another models fields?

Tags: django, django-models

Relatively new to Django. I think what I'm trying to do is very simple but I've never done this before. "irrelevant2" is an attribute in my class "one" that I want to refer to a direct element in the class "two" (this part is working fine).

Additionally, I want there to be a field called RELEVANT_VARIABLE in my class "one" that is essentially a dropdown menu that chooses between two elements of the class "two" and can only pick one. I understand that I need a form but so far have not been successful.

My hunch says RELEVANT_VARIABLE should be a ForeignKey but I'm not sure how to attach it to a dropdown of either attr1 or attr2 from class "two".

```
class two(models.Model):
    attr1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    attr2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class one(models.Model):

    irrelevant1 = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    irrelevant2 = models.ForeignKey(two, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    RELEVANT_VARIABLE = models.ManyToManyField(two, related_name="team_selection")
```

And then in forms.py

```
class OneForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     super(OneForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     self.fields[**not sure what to even put here**] = forms.ChoiceField(
         choices=[(o[**not sure**], str(o[**not sure**])) for o in Two.objects.filter(irrelevant2=self)]
     )
class Meta:
    model = two
```

Comment: Will the `RELEVENT_VARIABLE` field in the form have only two choices, or will it vary according to the instances in `two`?

Comment: it varies based on the instance of two, and it will always be the corresponding attr1 and attr2 in the instance of two indicated by the foreign key in irrelevant2

Comment: So, for example if there are two instances of `two` with field values`("one",1) and("two",2)` for atrr1 and attr2 respectively, do you want the `RELEVANT_VARIABLE` form field to be `<select ><option value=1>One</option><option value=2 >Two</option></select>`

Comment: @Mugoma yes exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will  need a simple foreign key.

```py
class two(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        ###You are definining the "visible" name of each instance
        return self.attr1#or attr2, as desired

class one(models.Model):
    ...
        RELEVANT_VARIABLE = models.ForeignKey(two, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**forms.py**

```py
from django import forms
from .models import two
class OneForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = two
        fields ="__all__"
```

Your `RELEVANT_VARIABLE` field will be

```html
<select ...>
    <option value="instance1.pk">instance1.attr1</option>
    <option value="instance2.pk">instance2.attr1</option>
...
</select>
```

If `RELEVANT_VARIBALE` id to link to multiple instances of `two`, only **models.py** will need to change

```py
class one(models.Model):
    ...
        RELEVANT_VARIABLE = models.ManyToManyField(two)
```

References:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm almost there. I see the part where you used the <select> tags for the dropdown. However, I want this structure to be internal. I essentially want the structure to be set up in a way that I have a dropdown menu when I look on the admin page that only has the two attributes for the corresponding class "two" element. Currently I'm getting full class "two" objects instead of the attributes for the corresponding class "two" object.

Comment: If you need to **display** the two attributes, you could modify the` def __str__(self):` method to show what you want. The html in the answer is the [default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) rendering of the field

Comment: I think I might have been a bit unclear. I want the value of RELEVANT_VARIABLE to be a choice between attr1 and attr2 of the corresponding class "two" instance. The corresponding class "two" instance is designated with the irrelevant2 field.

Comment: I don't think dbs store choices(not sure). However,[JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) might be what you are looking for. Or a simple CharField. A bit more context on why you want `RELEVANT_VARIABLE` to contain choices might help

Comment: It makes sense, i think i’ll just go with a charfield I appreciate your help!